# tomcat startup.sh not running

Tags: tomcat, localhost

i'm trying to use tomcat7 to develop something.

I'm on a elementaryOS (luna) (ubuntu 12.04) and i installed tomcat as an instance of the package tomcat7-user like explained in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310767/how-should-i-install-apache-tomcat-7-for-use-with-eclipse).

So, when i go to `~/my/path/bin` and execute `./startup.sh` i got this output:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/eduardo/_dev/servers/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/eduardo/_dev/servers/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started
```

it seems to be everything fine, but when i check `sudo service tomcat7 status` it shows me that it was not started:

```
 * Tomcat servlet engine is not running.
```

and (obviosly) i can't reach anything in localhost:8080.

Any tips???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: already tried this way? `sudo service tomcat7 start`

Comment: OK, some progress. i got `* invalid CATALINA_BASE: /var/lib/tomcat7`
now i need to know where CATALINA_BASE is set to change it to my folder, do you know where can i do it?

Comment: anyway, i guess that by doing `sudo service tomcat7 start` i'm not starting the instance that i declared before...

Comment: maybe you start your tomcat from your own path. but you check tomcat status of installed package. 
try this command to check which is listen on port 8080 
`sudo netstat -ltnp | grep 8080`

Comment: yeah bekt you were right. i changed the variables to my instance and now i got it!

Thank you very much for you help.